# Merge 2 groups in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have 2 host groups in my inventory in ansible as follows:

```
[loadbalancer-add]
172.23.130.97
172.23.130.98

[loadbalancer-remove]
172.23.130.99
172.23.130.100
```

I would like to merge these groups to pass them to a loadbalancer API so I can add a server, then remove a server.  So I need to merge the groups to create a group as follows:

```
[loadbalancer]
172.23.130.97
172.23.130.99
172.23.130.98
172.23.130.100
```

I have the following task but it is not producing the correct output

```
- name: Merge Dictionaries
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: localhost
  become: true
  no_log: false

  tasks:
    - add_host:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        ansible_ssh_port: 2020
        action: remove
        group: loadbalancer
      with_items:
        - "{{ groups['loadbalancer-remove'] }}"
        - "{{ groups['loadbalancer-add'] }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
```

This produces

```
[loadbalancer]
172.23.130.99
172.23.130.100
172.23.130.97
172.23.130.98
```

Is it possible to get the output that I require?

Thanks

Comment: Ah sorry thats a typo, I'll fix it now

Comment: Sorry about that I've updated the question

Comment: I'd like the final list to first have one of the hosts to remove from the LB (i.e. an item from `loadbalancer-remove` then a host to add to add to the LB (i.e. an item from `loadbalancer-add`.  I'd put the order slightly wrong in my question which I have now corrected

Answer (score 1):

May be this is what you need:

```
[loadbalancer-add]
172.23.130.97
172.23.130.98

[loadbalancer-remove]
172.23.130.99
172.23.130.100

[loadbalancer:children]
loadbalancer-remove
loadbalancer-add
```

So now you could reference as one group

```
groups['loadbalancer']*
```

.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.  I don't think this will merge the lists as I need though, it will append one to the other.

Answer (score 1):

I did manage to find a way of doing this.  It may not be the best way but here is my solution anyway:

```
- name: Merge Dictionaries
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: localhost
  no_log: false

  vars:
    merged_lb_hosts: |
      {% if (groups['loadbalancer-add'] | length) >= (groups['loadbalancer-remove'] | length) %}
        {% for i in range(0, groups['loadbalancer-add'] | length) -%}
          {{ groups['loadbalancer-add'][i] | default('') }}:add|{{ groups['loadbalancer-remove'][i] | default('') }}:remove|
        {%- endfor %}
      {% else %}
        {% for i in range(0, groups['loadbalancer-remove'] | length) -%}
          {{ groups['loadbalancer-add'][i] | default('') }}:add|{{ groups['loadbalancer-remove'][i] | default('') }}:remove|
        {%- endfor %}
      {% endif %}

  tasks:
    - debug: msg="{{ merged_lb_hosts }}"
    - add_host:
        name: "{{ item.split(':')[0] }}"
        action: "{{ item.split(':')[1] }}"
        ansible_ssh_port: 2020
        group: loadbalancer
      with_items:
        - "{{ (merged_lb_hosts | trim()).split('|') }}"
      when: "{{item.split(':')[0] != ''}}"
```

This will take the add and remove groups and merge them into a var called `merged_lb_hosts`

The `add_host` task will split this var in it `with_items` section to create an iterable list.

It feels very hacky but it does the job that I was after